# Method returns object instead of type explicitly casted in generics method

Tags: java, generics

I was trying to get my head around generics of java. And it seems difficult to implement what I want.

I want to make a generic task aggregator. Meaning, given a list of request, I need to process each request through some handler (that is obtained from a factory based on request). And return the list of response. Now to speed up the process, I want to obtain the results by executing handlers in parallel.

First I've define a interface `THandler`:

```
interface THandler<Request, Response> {
        Response handle(Request request);
}
```

This is my aggregator:

```
public class AggTasks
{
    public static <Request, Response> long aggregate(List <Request> req, List <Response> res) {

        CountDownLatch allDone = new CountDownLatch(req.size());
        List <TWork<Request, Response>> workers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Request r : req) {
            // Getting error: The constructor TWork<Request,Response>(THandler<Request,Object>, Request, CountDownLatch) is undefined
            workers.add(new TWork<Request, Response>(getHandler(r), r, allDone));
        }

        for (TWork<Request, Response> w : workers) {
            new Thread(w).start();
        }
        allDone.await();
        for (TWork<Request, Response> w : workers) {
            res.add(w.collectResponse());
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is my `TWork`:

```
class TWork<Request, Response> implements Runnable{

        private THandler<Request, Response> handler;
        private Request request;
        private Response response;

        public TWork(THandler<Request, Response> tHandler, Request r, CountDownLatch allDone)
        {
            this.handler = tHandler;
            this.request = r;
        }

        public Response collectResponse() {
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            response = handler.handle(request);
        }

    }
```

Finally here is `getHandler()` and `FactoryHandler`. I tried explicitly casting the return value to `THandler<Request, Response>`, however, still at compile time it's showing as `THandler<Request,Object>`:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <Request, Response> THandler<Request, Response> getHandler(Request req) {
        return (THandler<Request, Response>) FactoryHandler.getHandler(req);
    }

    class FactoryHandler {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static <Request, Response> THandler<Request, Response> getHandler(Request req) {
            return (THandler<Request, Response>) new StringHandler();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions to improve the design is welcome.

**Edit:**
I tried the suggestion of `Wietlol`: and it seems to work if I skip call to `static` method `getHandler()`:

```
workers.add(new TWork<Request, Response>(FactoryHandler.<Request, Response>getHandler(r), r, allDone));
```

Comment: If you know the classes(Request and Response) then you don't need generic implementation. Generic only helps when you don't want to hard-coded type and want to intercept multiple implementation type.

Comment: FactoryHandler.getHandler is defined incorrectly. Remove <Request, Response> after static keyword

Comment: @JugalPanchal: Request & Response are not classes. They are generic types. I named them this way so that it's more meaningful

Comment: @rebelizant I don't want FactoryHandler to be a generic type. For the same reason I provided a static generic method. It gives me compile error after removing `<Request, Response>`. Can you elaborate what do you mean?

Comment: Don't name generic parameters the same as classes; follow the convention of using single upper-case letters. It's confusing as heck the way you did it.

Answer (score 2):

```
FactoryHandler.getHandler(req);
```

Only defines the type of "Request", implicitly defined by the type of "req".
Response is not defined and thus predicted as Object to make it work with everything.

The easiest solution would be to call "getHandler()" like this:

```
FactoryHandler.<Request, Response>getHandler(req);
```

Which explicitly defines the generic types.

Comment: Tried this. Still getting: `The constructor TWork<Request,Response>(THandler<Request,Object>, Request, CountDownLatch) is undefined`. Thanks though.

Comment: workers.add(new TWork<Request, Response>(getHandler(r), r, allDone)); should have the same solution, aka, add "<Request, Response>" just before "getHandler()"

Comment: it works if I skip call static method `getHandler()` directly to `FactoryHandler.<Request, Response>getHandler(req);`. Can you update how can I make the static method work?

Comment: what do you mean with skip call?